# question about handling loss of database connection in JSF app

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I have a JSF app with the DAO layer implemented for Hibernate (also using Spring for transaction management).

The problem I'm having is occasionally the database goes down and when this happens I want the JSF app to redirect to a "Lost connection to the database" page.

There's two approaches I can think of to handle this:

(1) a phase listener that tests the database connection on every request and redirects if the database is not there; (except that means an extra database query on every web app request)

(2) have every method in every DAO throw some kind of "NoDBConnectionExcepiton" and catch that exception in the backing beans and redirect there (except that means writing a lot of exception handling code)

Does anyone have any ideas?  Suggestion and advice are appreciated!

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *have every method in every DAO throw some kind of "NoDBConnectionExcepiton"*

I'd go for this. You can let it be a subclass of some exception which it is already throwing, so that you don't need to change the `throws` or `catch` clauses. For example, a subclass of `SQLException` maybe?

> *and catch that exception in the backing beans and redirect there (except that means writing a lot of exception handling code)*

Not necessarily. You can define a custom error page for a specific exception in `web.xml` so that the container will handle it by itself.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>com.example.NoDBConnectionException</exception-type>
    <location>/errors/dbconnection.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Comment: I like this idea, but OP states that he uses Hibernate in DAO. Hibernate doesn't let SQLException escape and translates it into a runtime exception HibernateException. So it would require adding all that try/catch/throw scaffolding to each DAO method, adding throws clause to each of them and then adding try/catch to the service methods calling DAOs anyway.

Comment: @Olaf: Ah I overlooked that bit. I'd then let it extend `HibernateException` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate already throws unchecked HibernateException when something is wrong. If your application is (reasonably) bug-free, you may interpret all HibernateExceptions as indications that the database is down and treat them as such. A bonus from it being a RuntimeException: you chose at what layer of your application you handle them.

Comment: Hi Olaf; My prob with that idea is I have everything decoupled like *.JSF->Handler.java->Service.java->DAO.java->Hibernate; and each layer catches exceptions and handles them or throws it or a new exception up to the next layer; to do what you're suggesting i'd have to explicitly add throws/catch HiberateException at all layers so the Handler.java can redirect appropriately, but DAO layer is the only one that has knowledge that Hibernate is even in the implementation so it pretty much breaks the decoupled design.

Comment: @Robert Hume: Well, some layer needs to be aware that the DAO layer is talking to the database. It may, as well, know that it talks to it via Hibernate. I would suggest catching Hibernate exceptions in the Service layer and rethrowing them as checked, using your example, NoDBConnectionExceptions.